# How to use simple function written for nodejs in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I came across `myFunction` on github. It doesn't use any special APIs and is just plain JavaScript. But the people that wrote the script, wrote it for nodejs, not the browser.

So on the `myFunction`'s github page, they have an example of how to use it:

In your console type:

```
npm install myFunction
```

This downloads a single js file in `/node_modules/myFunction/index.js`.

Then you are instructed to use it like so in your nodejs code:

```
var myFunc = require('myFunction');
myFunc.doSomething();
```

But I want to run the function in the browser.

I tried embeding the file `/node_modules/myFunction/index.js` in a `<script>` tag but it comes up with the error: `module is not defined`

I tried just modifying the code a little bit to get rid of the module.exports part at the top but I can't figure that out.

So I find out about browserify

```
browserify /node_modules/myFunction/index.js > myFunctionBrowser.js
```

Embed the script in my site

```
<script src="myFunctionBrowser.js"></script>
```

And can confirm in dev tools that the script is being loaded.

But now what?

I try

```
<script src="myFunctionBrowser.js"></script>
<script>
    var myFunc = require('myfunction');
    myFunc.doSomething();
</script>
```

But I get: `require is not defined`

I try

```
<script src="myFunctionBrowser.js"></script>
<script>
    myFunction.doSomething()
</script>
```

But `myFunction is not defined`

How do I access myFunction after browserify-ing? Or am I using the wrong thing for what I want?

Comment: Hey You cannot use the "require" statement in client side. Not in plain js. 
If you want help how to use your function, we need a little more details on this specific function. What you described here is totally find : you cannot use require (which is a NodeJS server side statement). If you use webpack for exemple you could use the import statement....

Comment: The problem is nodeJS is not client side javascript.  Its server side.  What you need to do is setup a simple request handler in your nodejs app. A popular option is expressJS.  Then on your server side you just make a GET request to your server from the client side and you can run any code you desire.  I would lookup axios or fetch for making the request from client side to server side.

Comment: thanks @yAzou . documentation link?

Comment: have you tried calling it simply as "doSomething()" after loading it via the script tag like in your last code snippet. If you declared the function then, it attaches to the global namespace.

Comment: @Luv not defined

Answer (score 0):

Use [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/).

Following the [documentation for RequireJS on CommonJS modules](https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html)

1. Copy `/node_modules/myFunction/index.js`
    to `myFunctionBrowser.js`
2. Wrap everything in `myFunctionBrowser.js` 
   with `define(function(require, exports, module) {//code here//});`
3. Replace the line `module.exports = function(...` 
   with `return function(...`
4. Include require `<script src="require.js"></script>`
5. Include your new browser function

```
<script>    
   require(['myFunctionBrowser.js'], function(doSomething){
       doSomething()
   });
</script>
```

I suspect in some cases this may work:

```
<script>    
   require(['myFunctionBrowser.js'], function(myFunc){
       myFunc.doSomething()
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a webserver like express to invoke functions from browser. here is code snippet

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const myFunc = require('myFunction');

app.get('/', (req, res) => () => {
  const output = myFunc.doSomething()
  res.json(output);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

This will start the web server at port 3000 and going to the URL will invoke the function.

Comment: But the source code for doSomething is `function(a, b){return a + b}`. Wouldn't it be better to run that from the browser? The browser is capable, its just the code is formatted a little wrong for the browser

Comment: ```myFunc.doSomething()``` will run the code in the browser if you are working in a nodeJS environment. If your code is returning you can use the ```res.send``` method and it will display the output in browser.